# connection refused when using git local network

Tags: linux, git, ssh, config, raspbian

I have tried to setup git on raspberry pi. I went through this tutorial: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server.

I generated SSH keys using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` and then pasted those into .ssh/id_rsa file and then used `cat .ssh/id_rsa >> authorized_keys`. I then followed the rest of the tutorial and made a new directory and ran `git init --bare`.

On a seperate windows pc on the same local network, in cygwin terminal I then tried `git clone ssh:\\UserName@hostIPaddress:/path/to/new/directory/for/git/project`.

I get an error message saying `ssh: connect to host <IP address> port <port>: Connection refused`. Googling suggests this is an authentication issue and I am not familiar with SSH. Do I need to give the SSH keys to the local windows computer who is trying to clone the git repo? If so, how?

new to git and ssh and trying to get git running

Comment: "*Connection refused*" is not an authentication issue, it's network issue. You don;t need SSH keys (yes), you need to resolve the issue at the network or server level. Do you run `sshd` (SSH server) at the `hostIPaddress` host?

Comment: check on the "server" if the port is open, for starters. Is it the raspberry? With a linux? Then `netstat -lntp` should list port 22 as being open.... if it is open, make sure that traffic from the client is hitting it by using `tshark`, for example.

Comment: Thank you both. I tried sshd first but it said no such service exists so I tried to install it and it still wouldnt work. Then I tried service ssh restart and now I can clone, commit and push my changes. One thing I dont understand is, why does the windows PC not need those SSH keys? Why did I need to generate them and leave them on the git server only? What are those SSH keys doing?

Comment: The package to install should be `openssh-server`, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: When you try to run an operation now, does it request password? If it _does_, then that is why you don't need to setup the keys on the windows box. If you set them correctly on the client, you should be able to interact with the server without needing to provide the password for the user on the raspberry box.

Comment: I went through the commands again and it was openssh-server that I installed. Yes it asked me for the password when cloning. I guess I need to look at how to set it up correctly so that it does not require a password every time.

Comment: You meed to place the _public_ key in the wondows box at the right default location so that git can pick it up _or_ I think there are settings so that git picks it up at a random location.... or by using `ssh-add` you can add it and then git should be able to use it.

Comment: Are you able to `ssh` to the machine to get a shell? If not, I recommend solving that first.

Comment: "Do I need to give the SSH keys to the local windows computer who is trying to clone the git repo?" You say you generated SSH keys. Which machine did you do that on? You should do it on the client machine (or at least that's the way I do it). In this case, I think that means the Windows machine. Then you copy the public key from the windows machine to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the server where you are hosting git.

Comment: `cat .ssh/id_rsa >> authorized_keys` copies the private key into the authorized keys. DON'T DO THAT! This potentially exposes your private key. Fortunately it shouldn't be a problem since you are just doing this with files on the same machine. Just be sure to edit `authorized_keys` and remove the lines that contain the private key. Then generate a key on the Windows computer and copy `id_rsa.pub` from your Windows machine to `authorized_keys` on the linux machine.

Comment: thanks eftshift0 and code-apprentice. I could try the ssh-add for windows pc. I generated the SSH keys on raspberry (server). So if I understand this correctly. Generate ssh key on client (windows machine) then copy this SSH key to authorize_keys on raspberry (server)?